# Set a new value depending on what the original value is?

Tags: drupal, twig

In Drupal views, I have a twig variable available to me called `{{ name }}`. This stores a list of taxonomy terms depending on the type of content used. I currently have a function running something like this that works:

```
{% if name == "Tax1" %}
  <a href="file1.pdf" class="stat" target="_blank" title="Download File">Download</a>
{% elseif name == "Tax2" %}
  <a href="file2.pdf" class="stat" target="_blank" title="Download File">Download</a>
{% endif %}
```

However, I feel like there is a better way for me to go about doing this. As an example isn't something like this supposed to work?

```
{%
  set newval = [
    name == "Tax1" ? 'file1.pdf' : 'file2.pdf'
  ]
%}
<a href="{{ newval }}" class="stat" target="_blank" title="Download File">Download</a>
```

Pretty much what I'm trying to state above is, if the value of name is equal to "Tax1", print out file1.pdf, else print file2.pdf.

I have very basic twig knowledge and I haven't touched it in a couple years so if anyone could help me out with this, that would be great.

Comment: Why are you creating an array when you want a string?

Comment: @DarkBee what I'm trying to create is what I have above but in less code. I know it's possible, I just can't remember/figure out how. I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: `<a href="{{ name == "Tax1" ? "file1.pdf" : "file2.pdf" }}" class="stat" target="_blank" title="Download File">Download</a>`

Comment: @DarkBee thanks so much...i was thinking about if that would work or not. Now, what if there was a third option? Ex Tax1, Tax2 & Tax3 with 3 options for files? Something similar?

Comment: I would add a filter/function to twig if you want to transform that from up to more than one value tbh

Comment: Hmm, ok, i guess I'll have to look into that more then cause I just realized that I do in fact need that 3rd option due to if it's not one of the first two terms, I need another default anchor link displayed.

Comment: Yeah def add a filter then you can do `{{ name|file('default.pdf') }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DarkBee for the help. I must have been overthinking as the answer was fairly simple.

The below solution worked for what I was initially asking:

```
<a href="{{ name == "Tax1" ? "file1.pdf" : "file2.pdf" }}" class="stat" target="_blank" title="Download File">Download</a>
```

However, I ended up needing a third default option if not the first two so the below code is what I ended up using:

```
  {% if name == "Tax1" or name == "Tax2" %}
    <a href="{{ name == 'Tax1' ? 'file1.pdf' : 'file2.pdf' }}" class="stat" target="_blank" title="Download File">Download</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="stat">Other Option</span>
  {% endif %}
```